# Execute shell functions like explain() with mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB driver to retrieve data https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
I was trying to explain() the query but this documentation doesn't mention anything related.
How can I use this function with the MongoDB driver? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

I want to do something like with Go Driver

```
db.col.find({filter:1}).explain("executionStats")
```

Comment: That IS a tag. You have the [go] tag. That tells us what language you're using. Putting it in the title, too, is incorrect. It's noisy. It's ugly. It serves no purpose. This is a [long-established site guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/165502).

Comment: Hi, try explain() on Mongo Shell.

Comment: @HanielBaez it works on Mongo Shell but I need to generate reports for slow queries using Go driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in Go driver source that implements explain.

However, you can send the explain command yourself using the generic command helper (equivalent of https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-database-tasks/#arbitrary-comands). See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/ for the explain command syntax. You would need to manually construct the find *command* from the find *query* you normally use, easiest way to do this is to use command monitoring to see what commands are being sent.

Answer (score 1):

you can use RunCmd, for example

```golang
func ExampleDatabase_RunCommand() {
    var db *mongo.Database

    // Run an explain command to see the query plan for when a "find" is
    // executed on collection "bar" specify the ReadPreference option to
    // explicitly set the read preference to primary.
    findCmd := bson.D{{"find", "bar"}}
    command := bson.D{{"explain", findCmd}}
    opts := options.RunCmd().SetReadPreference(readpref.Primary())
    var result bson.M
    err := db.RunCommand(context.TODO(), command, opts).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```